# clustering with NA values in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I was surprised to find out that `clara` from `library(cluster)` allows NAs. But function documentation says nothing about how it handles these values.

So my questions are:

1. How `clara` handles NAs?
2. Can this be somehow used for `kmeans` (Nas not allowed)?

**[Update]** So I did found lines of code in `clara` function:

```
inax <- is.na(x)
valmisdat <- 1.1 * max(abs(range(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
x[inax] <- valmisdat
```

which do missing value replacement by `valmisdat`. Not sure I understand the reason to use such formula. Any ideas? Would it be more "natural" to treat NAs by each column separately, maybe replacing with mean/median?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although not stated explicitly, I believe that `NA` are handled in the manner described in the `?daisy` help page. The Details section has:

> In the daisy algorithm, missing values in a row of x are not included in the dissimilarities
>   involving that row.

Given internally the same code will be being used by `clara()` that is how I understand that `NA`s in the data can be handled - they just don't take part in the computation. This is a reasonably standard way of proceeding in such cases and is for example used in the definition of Gower's generalised similarity coefficient.

**Update** The `C` sources for `clara.c` clearly indicate that this (the above) is how `NA`s are handled by `clara()` (lines 350-356 in `./src/clara.c`):

```
    if (has_NA && jtmd[j] < 0) { /* x[,j] has some Missing (NA) */
        /* in the following line (Fortran!), x[-2] ==> seg.fault
           {BDR to R-core, Sat, 3 Aug 2002} */
        if (x[lj] == valmd[j] || x[kj] == valmd[j]) {
        continue /* next j */;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Same code lines to treat missing values in `daisy` as in `clara` function (see my question update).

Comment: @danas.zuokas I'm not sure how helpful it is to just pull arbitrary lines of code from the sources that you think a related to the question. You need to study both the R code and the C code. `valmisdat` is the value used to indicate missing data (`NA`) in the C code rather than have it use `NA` directly. If you look at the C code you will see that it clearly just ignores comparisons where a variable has a missing value for one or the other or both of the samples for which the dissimilarity is being computed. See the updated answer for the pointer to the code.

Comment: Can you think of ways to employ same NA handling in `kmeans`?

Comment: Possibly but not without writing your own k-means algorithm. Essentially k-means works on the within-group sums of squares so distances to the centroid. `clara` is doing the same thing so the idea is feasible (you just ignore those comparisons when computing the Euclidean distance to the centroid and of the centroid itself I guess). Are you fixed on using k-means? If k-mediods is OK (and I don't see why it won't be as it is more robust than k-means), use the `pam()` function in the **cluster** package, which handles `NA`s like `clara()` and `daisy()`.

Comment: @GavinSimpson did you have scalability issues using a matrix-oriented approach before k-means? Depending on memory allocation in r, the vector may be too large.

Comment: @ScottDavis not really - I have 64Gb RAM :-) and no problems have exhausted that yet. I see your point, but you need the entire dissimilarity object to do k-means in R so this is an issue regardless of `NA`s, no? Or am I not following?

Comment: @GavinSimpson Yes, I agree you need the whole dataset for k-means. Just wanted to bring up a problem that might happen. :) I had a dataset where the daisy package wouldn't load because I did not have enough RAM.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if `kmeans` can handle missing data by ignoring the missing values in a row.

There are two steps in `kmeans`;

1. calculating the distance between an observation and original cluster mean.
2. updating the new cluster mean based on the newly calculated distances.

When we have missing data in our observations:
Step 1 can be handled by adjusting the distance metric appropriately as in the `clara/pam/daisy` package. But Step 2 can only be performed if we have some value for each column of an observation. Therefore imputing might be the next best option for `kmeans` to deal missing data.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the Clara c code, I noticed that in clara algorithm, when there are missing values in the observations, the sum of squares is "reduced" proportional to the number of missing values, which I think is wrong! line 646 of [clara.c](https://svn.r-project.org/R-packages/trunk/cluster/src/clara.c) is like " dsum *= (nobs / pp) " which shows it counts the number of non-missing values in each pair of observations (nobs), divides it by the number of variables (pp) and multiplies this by the sum of squares. I think it must be done in other way, i.e. " dsum *= (pp / nobs) ".

Comment: You can use an [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35925440/edit) to edit your previous answer.